# How to set JScrollPane to show only a sepecific amount of rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I only need a table to show 3 rows which get top 3 selling products from DB. The table is ready, but the there's a huge portion of table which is practically empty, except for 3 rows. How can I set height of this scrollpane to match the height of 3 rows?

SOLUTION:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a quirk of the JTable's Scrollable implementation: it sets an arbitrary fixed prefScrollable size.

<strike>You null it to make the scrollPane to fall back to using the table's preferredSize:</strike>

> <strike>table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(null);</strike>

**Edit**

outch, @vedran is correct, that's not always working in a core table with core layoutManagers (it was a [nice hack in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773107/miglayout-confused-by-jtable-objects-contained-in-jscrollbar-objects/9787293#9787293) :) sorry for the confusion. Copying his comment here:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

is a viable option, though all the usual bewares about hard-coding sizes apply here as well.

A well-behaved JTable would implement a more reasonable getPreferredScrollableViewportSize, f.i calculating it in terms of content. JXTable (which is the best-behaved table, biased me :-), you could set the pref in terms of visible rows, just as in a list:

```
xtable.setVisualRowCount(3);
```

Comment: +1, I guess you got it better of me again :-) , but won't setting it to null, will wipe out the whole `JTable` from the view ?

Comment: @GagandeepBali no. column names will still be visible :)

Comment: +1, please my stupid question, is there difference betweens `XxxViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize)` and yours `XxxViewportSize(null)` in the case of rows don't have got the same Height

Comment: Actually `table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());`
 will set the correct height

Comment: @mKorbel the difference is that my suggestion is _not_ working reliably, see edit :-)

Comment: @vedran : Actually keeping that to null, made my `JTable` display nothing. Might be the difference in LayoutManager :-)